# I need a Regex expression to verify a file found starts with specific letters from a File::Find::Name

Tags: regex

I have the following find routine that searches a directory and sub directories for files that are older than 5 days and removes them.

```
{
find (sub {my $filename = $File::Find::name;
  if ( -f $filename ) {
      my $filetime = (stat "$filename")[9];
      my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month, $year) = (localtime($filetime))[0,1,2,3,4,5];
      if ($now - $fivedaystime > $filetime){
        push (@file_list, $filename);
        }
      }
}, $pslog_directory);
}
```

It all works great but now I need to remove the files that are older than 5 days AND start with the characters "Log".

I wanted to add a regex expression but I can't figure the correct way to write the regex expression out. I went to a few regex web sites and there is a lot of information that I need to study but I needed this one quickly. This is what I tried but it is not working as it does not find any files to remove when there are many that start with "Log" in the directory:

if ( -f $filename and $filename =~ '^Log')

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hello @Rik, I am using Perl

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Perl, the syntax would be:

`if ((-f $filename) and ($filename =~ /^Log/))`

If you'd like it to be case insensitive use:

`($filename =~ /^Log/i)`